# How to keep dialog box inside the angular material popup

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog

I would like to open a confirm modal dialog inside the popup. any one help me? where there is 2nd popup open, 1st popup should not be accessed by user. so required to add a layer within modal level.

But not able to achieve the same. any one help me?

here is the [Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-dialogs-so-gjypnz?file=app/dialog2.component.html)

Comment: what you shared is working properly, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-dialogs-so-wdkp9h) give screenshots as to what you want, currently this seems fine to me!

Comment: @Naren Murali can you check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-dialogs-so-gjypnz?file=app/dialog2.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You should open the second dialog in the same way you opened the first one: `this.dialog.open(Dialog2Component` and your problem will be solved

Comment: can you please update my stackbliz? from where it should be called?

Comment: looks like you already did it but commented it out. From Dialog1Component
https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-dialogs-so-e9n5ps?file=app%2Fdialog1.component.ts

Comment: No this not the one i look for. I nee to keep the 2nd popup under the boundary of first popup. it should not global level. it should nested inside the popup